# How can I reduce the sound of clicking my mouse

Tags: technology, sound

I have a wonderful mouse except... I'd like it to click more silently (left and right buttons). Probably it was that loud, probably it is the work of Time, but the current sound doesn't suit me now, especially at night.

Any ways to reduce this sound?

I also have a trackpad, which have no clicking sound (I can just tap), but I find the mouse to be more useful and convenient to use. Please don't recommend buying a new mouse or another device.

Comment: You can buy a quite mouse, e.g. http://smile.amazon.com/Noiseless-Optical-Gaming-Computer-JNL-101K/dp/B0042T7TBS/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1439422113&sr=8-2&keywords=quiet+mouse

Comment: Is it you or other people who are bothered by the sound? Would ear plugs be a solution?

Answer (score 12):

Two options:

1. Use a thick foam mouse pad.  Using a mouse on a hard desk will amplify the sound.
2. Take the mouse apart and insulate around the click switches (see image).  Felt, or thin foam would suffice, but the key is to maintain the function while adding something to dampen the sound (*Disclaimer: I have never done this!*).

[image: Image of click switches where insulation is needed]

As a third more drastic option, you could try and replace the click switches with ones that are less noisy.  Most likely more trouble than it's worth, and I can't actually provide a product/catalog # for ones don't make a sound.

Comment: Good options, thanks. Still, I'll wait for another options to arrive :)

Comment: Covers all the options I can think of, except using a noise generator to conceal the noise.

Comment: Be very careful when you open the mouse case, sometimes tiny little springs - about 4mm in length shoot out into a corner of the room you don't know exists.

Answer (score 8):

For a temporary solution you can simply put a scarf or any other kind of fabric over the mouse or only over the button you want to silence. Then just use it as normal, with the fabric between your fingers and the mouse. I've used this at school, while the teacher was talking and I was playing games and needed to click furiously. Without the scarf the teacher noticed I wasn't paying attention because of all the clicks he heard.

For a permanent solution I don't know anything except messing with the micro switches, which has already been posted as an answer.

Comment: Quite an interesting solution!

Comment: i've tried the fabric using a glove and it works actually pretty well.
btw i used it for playing League of legends (a lot of clicking) and nobody noticed

Answer (score 2):

You can open your mouse and apply few drops of oil (which is non-conductive) on the click mechanism, it should do the job.

See also:

- (video) [How to fix double clicking problem of any gaming mouse!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7JAVlIIvaM) at YouTube.

Comment: Are you sure that it won't damage my mouse...

Comment: @nicael Oil is non-conductive, so if you use a few drops, it won't do anything.

Comment: @nicael I've added link to the video which demonstrates something similar.

Comment: Oil is non-conductive, so if you use a few drops, you may break the switch, which relies on the conductivity between two surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I put chewing gum around the tiny switches inside the mouse. I think it lessened the noise a little bit. Can fill it p with some kind of foam later. Hope this will work for you too.