# Reduce Laptop Mouse Clicking Sound

Tags: technology, laptop

How do I reduce the mouse clicking sound on my lap top?
Every time I click on something the neighbor can hear me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reduce the sound of clicking my mouse?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/5533/how-can-i-reduce-the-sound-of-clicking-my-mouse) Or SE Sound Design [How do I remove mouse click noise](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/25789/how-do-i-remove-mouse-click-noise). Unless you mean the OS is producing an audio FX of the click, in which case turn it off in the settings.

Comment: How close is your neighbour? Where, in relation to you, is your neighbour located?

Comment: Can you use the touchpad?

Comment: Buy a silent mouse, they are marketed as such.

Comment: Replace with a touchpad that accepts a tap as a click, tap two fingers for right click.

Comment: is the clicking noise from a loud mouse, or is your operating system configured to make sounds when you click your mouse?

Answer (score 2):

The clicking sound is made by the actual switch inside the mouse. Is is done mechanically, so no software configuration in the world can adjust it.

The way I see it,  there are 2 solutions involving the the mouse:

- buy a new, silent mouse. Considering how cheap are mice today, that is the only option I recommend.
- replace the hardware switches inside the mouse with silent switches. Good luck finding the parts, cheaply. The replacement itself can be made by anyone with the tools and the skills to do electronics repairs. Buying a new mouse will be cheaper and more satisfactory, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried silent mouses like [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01JPOLKDW)?

I use a Logitech M330 and it is nearly silent.

Answer (score 0):

If using your keyboard is *silent enough*, offer your mouse a rest and use where possible short-cuts and key-bindings.

`Ctrl + C` and `Ctrl + V` to cut-and-paste are likely familiar to you.  You may gradually extend this knowledge, though.  On this page which I access with firefox, for example, I may advance to the next post on the same page by `j` and return to the previous by `k`, may jump to the open answer mask by `a`, access the inbox by `i`, etc.  Similar to the [vim editor](https://www.vim.org/), you may start using some of these key-bindings e.g., in [web browsers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/), [pdf viewers](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/), [image viewers](https://reposcope.com/package/vimiv), too.  While these examples are from using Linux, there equally are shortcuts and key bindings in programs for Windows and Mac.

Not to all situations are suitable for this approach; however where possible, given your hands stay more often on the keyboard with less travel back from and forth to the mouse, your work may become more focused. It is a technique you acquire gradually.